# how can i execute theos tweak on jailbreak device?

Tags: ios, cydia, tweak

i am a new comer for tweak development, as per different tutorial now i have little bit idea of theos but facing so much problems while creating tweaks for iphone, right now i am following

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started

for starting, but i dont know how to install this tweaks on device, please give me some guidance if you are aware about this

thanks.

Comment: I also have the same question at the same time while getting started with jailbreak tweak, I have to go through below link:
1. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup/iOS
2. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Troubleshooting
please make sure.. you need to install all this stuffs in iDevice, using a mobile terminal app.

Answer (score 0):

Try here: http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-getting-the-tools/

and here: http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/9561218739/jailbroken-development-starter-pack

Answer (score 0):

Now its more easy to develop tweaks using iOSOpenDev. Even you don't need to connect the Device via USB. You can simply deploy them wirelessly provided you configure the SSH in the iOS Device.

[http://www.iosopendev.com/][1]

Tip :
You need to respring only for the first time. Once the Tweak is installed, any further build changes will be reflected in the device without respringing.